# Watson Deep Learning: Experiment Builder, Command Line Interface and Python Client - maturity and features

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud

The Watson Machine Learning service provides three options for training deep learning models.  The [docs](https://dataplatform.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/ml_dlaas.html) list the following:

> There are several ways to train models Use one of the following
>   methods to train your model:
>
> - Experiment Builder
> - Command line interface (CLI)
> - Python client

I believe these approaches will differ with their **(1) maturity** and **(2) the features they support**.

What are the differences in these approaches?  To ensure this question meets the quality requirements, can you please provide a objective list of the differences? Providing your answer as a community wiki answer will also allow the answer to be updated over time when the list changes.

If you feel this question is not a good fit for stack overflow, please provide a comment listing why and I will do my best to improve it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Might be better to ask on askDW or get WML dev to blog it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasons to use these techniques depends on a user's skillset and how they are fitting the training/monitoring/deploying steps into their workflow:

**Command Line Interface (CLI)**
The CLI is useful for quick and random access to details about your training runs.  It's also useful if you're building a data science workflow using shell scripts.

**Python Library**
WML's python library allows users to integrate their model training+deployment into a programmatic workflow.  It can be used both within notebooks as well as via IDEs. The library has become the most widely used way for executing batch training experiments.

**Experiment Builder UI**
This is the "easy button" for executing batch training experiments within Watson Studio. It's a quick way to learn the basics of the batch training capabilities in Watson Studio.  At present, it's not expected that data scientists would use Experiment Builder as their primary way of starting batch training experiments.  Perhaps as Model Builder matures, this could change but the Python library is more flexible for integrating into production workflows.